# the evaluation model of the performance doesn't work

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to evaluate the performance of the model on the test set, by calling the model's evaluate method.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
```

after importing the libs
I uploaded the dataset

```
mnist_data = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist_data.load_data()
```

```
def scale_mnist_data(train_images, test_images):

    return (train_images/255, test_images/255)
scaled_train_images, scaled_test_images = scale_mnist_data(train_images, test_images)

scaled_train_images = scaled_train_images[..., np.newaxis]
scaled_test_images = scaled_test_images[..., np.newaxis]

def get_model(input_shape):
    
    model = Sequential([
                    Conv2D(filters=8, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation= 
                    relu', input_shape=input_shape),
                    MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
                    Flatten(),
                    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
                    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
                    Dense(10, activation='softmax')

                      ])
    return model
```

```
model = get_model(scaled_train_images[0].shape)
model.summary()
def compile_model(model):

    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.005)
    acc = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()
    mae = tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()
    
    model.compile(
                    optimizer = opt,
                    loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
                    metrics = ['acc', 'mae'] 
    )
compile_model(model)
def train_model(model, train_images, train_labels):
    
    history = model.fit(scaled_train_images, train_labels, epochs=5, 
              batch_size=256)
    return history
history = train_model(model, scaled_train_images, train_labels)

frame = pd.DataFrame(history.history)
acc_plot = frame.plot(y="acc", title="Accuracy vs Epochs", legend=False)
acc_plot.set(xlabel="Epochs", ylabel="acc")
acc_plot = frame.plot(y="loss", title = "Loss vs Epochs",legend=False)
acc_plot.set(xlabel="Epochs", ylabel="Loss")

def evaluate_model(model, scaled_test_images, test_labels):
    
    (test_loss, test_accuracy) = model.evaluate(scaled_test_images, 
                                 test_labels)
    return (test_loss, test_accuracy)
```

Now, the problem really comes from this part, which I have no idea why?

```
test_loss, test_accuracy = evaluate_model(model, scaled_test_images, test_labels)

print(f"Test loss: {test_loss}")
print(f"Test accuracy: {test_accuracy}")
```

I got this Error:

```
10000/1 [=================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================5s 499us/sample - loss: 0.0256 - acc: 0.9840 - mae: 4.3630
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-0cceed9839ec> in <module>
      1 # Run your function to evaluate the model
      2 
----> 3 test_loss, test_accuracy = evaluate_model(model, scaled_test_images, test_labels)
      4 
      5 print(f"Test loss: {test_loss}")

<ipython-input-15-2804922fd7ac> in evaluate_model(model, scaled_test_images, test_labels)
      9     Your function should return a tuple (test_loss, test_accuracy).
     10     """
---> 11     (test_loss, test_accuracy) = model.evaluate(scaled_test_images, test_labels)
     12     return (test_loss, test_accuracy)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

and the protection is correct in the model predict

the model pred I suppose to run afterwards is :

```
num_test_images = scaled_test_images.shape[0]

random_inx = np.random.choice(num_test_images, 4)
random_test_images = scaled_test_images[random_inx, ...]
random_test_labels = test_labels[random_inx, ...]

predictions = model.predict(random_test_images)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 2, figsize=(16, 12))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4, wspace=-0.2)

for i, (prediction, image, label) in enumerate(zip(predictions, random_test_images, random_test_labels)):
    axes[i, 0].imshow(np.squeeze(image))
    axes[i, 0].get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    axes[i, 0].get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    axes[i, 0].text(10., -1.5, f'Digit {label}')
    axes[i, 1].bar(np.arange(len(prediction)), prediction)
    axes[i, 1].set_xticks(np.arange(len(prediction)))
    axes[i, 1].set_title(f"Categorical distribution. Model prediction: {np.argmax(prediction)}")
    
plt.show()
```

[Prediction Results Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXPMu.png)

Comment: When you compiled your model, did you specify any metrics? `model.evaluate()` will only return multiple outputs if you specified them in `model.compile()`

Comment: @MrSoLoDoLo def compile_model(model):
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.005)
    acc = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()
    mae = tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()
    
    model.compile(
                    optimizer = opt,
                    loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
                    metrics = ['acc', 'mae'] 
    )

Comment: There lies the issue. `model.evaluate()` by default returns only `loss`. Since you specified an additional two metrics `acc` and `mae` in `model.compile()`, it will return a list of 3 outputs. Hence, try unpacking via `test_loss, test_accuracy, test_mae = evaluate_model(model, scaled_test_images, test_labels)`

Comment: An easy way to see how many metrics you have is via `print(model.metrics_names)`. Then you can unpack the tuple accordingly.

Comment: @MrSoLoDoLo still didn't work, I'll edit the code so you can modify it

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove one of the metrics `acc` or `mae`, the reason being that it's conflicting

```
model.compile(
    optimizer = opt,
    loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
    metrics = ['acc'] # this or metrics = ['mae']
)
```

Using the evaluate function will return the `loss` and either `acc` or `mae` depending on the one you set.

```
#using accuracy
(test_loss, test_accuracy) = model.evaluate(scaled_test_images, test_labels)
```

or

```
#using mae
(test_loss, test_mae) = model.evaluate(scaled_test_images, test_labels)
```

In your case, I would recommend using the 'acc' which is the accuracy since it's a classification problem, however, it depends on what you are using it for.

You can as well calculate the `mean absolute error` using the function `tf.keras.metrics.mean_absolute_error(x_valid, results)` .

Comment: Hi @kha please accept  and rate the answer if this solve your issue